# Android listview items are transparent how to make them opaque?

Tags: android, kotlin

I am using listview to show some items. The items are transparent due to which the components that should be hidden by the listview are visible. I have given background for the item and listview as #FFFFFFFF still the elements that should be hidden are visible through the empty space of the list view. what should I do?
I am using constraint layout, the listview initially has visibility "gone", when clicked on the edittext it is visible. Is it constraint layer issue or something else?

XML Code Dialog box

```
   <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_dialog_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="12dp"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="24dp"
        android:hint="@string/asan_name"
        android:inputType="none"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textColor="@color/app_on_primary"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:visibility="visible" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_dialog_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/asan_name"
        android:padding="12dp"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="24dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lv_names"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="24dp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:background="#FFFFFFFF"
        android:cacheColorHint="#FFFFFFFF"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/et_dialog_name"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_dialog_duration"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:text="Duration"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@color/app_on_primary"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/et_dialog_name" />

    <NumberPicker
        android:id="@+id/number_picker_minute"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_dialog_duration"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/tv_time_symbol"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_time_symbol"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=":"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@color/app_on_primary"
        android:textSize="50sp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/number_picker_minute"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/number_picker_second"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_dialog_duration"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

    <NumberPicker
        android:id="@+id/number_picker_second"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_dialog_duration"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/tv_time_symbol"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>
```

XML Code List Item

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="@drawable/background_list_item">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_name_select"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_default_image" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_name_select"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textColor="@color/app_on_primary"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/img_name_select"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/img_name_select"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/img_name_select"/>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image]
the list view is currently hidden

[image]

Dialog box code

```
dialogName.setOnClickListener {
            dialogName.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
            dialogNameSearch.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            dialogDropdownList.visibility = View.VISIBLE

            val arrAdapter = SelectListAdapter(this@CreateSetsActivity, nameList, imageList)
            dialogDropdownList.adapter = arrAdapter

            dialogNameSearch.addTextChangedListener(object: TextWatcher {

                override fun beforeTextChanged(p0: CharSequence?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) {

                }

                override fun onTextChanged(p0: CharSequence?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) {
                    arrAdapter.filter.filter(p0)
                }

                override fun afterTextChanged(p0: Editable?) {

                }
            })

            dialogDropdownList.setOnItemClickListener(object: AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {
                override fun onItemClick(p0: AdapterView<*>?, p1: View?, p2: Int, p3: Long) {
                    dialogName.text = arrAdapter.getItem(p2)

                    dialogName.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                    dialogDropdownList.visibility = View.GONE
                    dialogNameSearch.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
                    dialogNameSearch.clearComposingText()
                }
            })
        }
```

Comment: Please edit your question and show the XML layout for the list item

Comment: @DavidWasser edited

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question with the images and code you've provided. It isn't clear what the problem is.